# Android : "All On/Off" sub action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

What's the name of the very useful grey "sub action bar" that usually contains a switch button to enable/disable every settings?

Like this one :

[image]

Or this one :

[image]

Comment: Seems like a normal Switch with dark background. You can always just check the view hierarchy by using Hierarchy Viewer